# No mostrar registros duplicados

Tags: mysql, android

Buen dia tengo mi siguiente consulta con la cual intento mostrar todos los registros de mi tabla `plan_embarque` pero por cada registro en esa tabla puede llegar a tener 3 o 4 fotos registradas en mi tabla `tb_image` pero al realizar la consulta me muestra todos los registros duplicados y solo quiero que me muestre uno.

`SELECT * FROM plan_embarque,tb_image WHERE liberado='' AND accion='Carga' AND id_emb = id_plan ORDER BY id_emb ASC;`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya utilize distinct pero me muestra solo una columna y las requiero todas pero en ves de mostrarme todos los registros requiero que se muestre solo uno ya que los vizualizo en un recyclerview.

Y como pueden ver en la foto se duplican

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haz un group by con id_emb o plant_code.

```
SELECT * FROM plan_embarque,tb_image 
WHERE liberado='' AND accion='Carga' AND id_emb = id_plan 
GROUP BY id_emb
ORDER BY id_emb ASC
```